# Excel `LN(x)` in javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel

I thought excel's LN(x) function simply calculates a natural log with base E, which in javascript corresponds to "Math.log()" if I understood correctly:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30893489/880837

I have these in excel for comparison, calculated using `=LN(x)`, where x = value on left:
[image]

Yet in JS, this doesn't match up with the result of Math.log(x):

- Math.log(0.55) = -0.5978370007556204
- Math.log(0.53) = -0.6348782724359695

And so on. It's nowhere near what I expected, any ideas what's missing? How do I do the same thing as excel's LN(x) in javascript?

Comment: When I type `=LN(0.55)` into an Excel cell I get exactly the same answer as the JavaScript function returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your excel spreadsheet, because those numbers are not what you should get from doing LN of the numbers in your first column

[image]

Comment: Oh darn it, decimals hidden in the spreadsheet. Math.log(0.545148834130875) == -0.6066964314528256. I'm an idiot, been fighting this for a while...

Comment: Ah, i was just about to add something about that, since i noticed there are multiple 0.61s, with different results. Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: Feel silly for missing it but appreciate the nudge :)